# C# Serialport or USB HID connection?

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb, hid

For my project I need to communicate with an Cypress PSoC5. I can use a serial connection or a USB HID connection.

I created a C# project for sending and reading data to/from PSoC5. Right now I'm using the ReceivedData event of the serialport to get notified if there is new data. Basically my project can either receive a datastream that should be plotted in realtime or just some settings I want to update within the GUI.

Right now I face the problem that the ReceivedData event fires very often (every 32 bytes), which is of course not good when there is a datastream. Basically I receive 24000 bytes per second if I get data for the plot. I know I can adjust the ReceivedBytesThreshold, but then I will not get an event for data below the threshold.

Can anyone tell if there is an approach to handle this?

Would it be an advantage to use the PSoC5 as a HID device instead?

Comment: It is entirely unclear to me why this is a problem.  A Socket is commonly used in a .NET project, it can easily sustain a data rate of 5 *megabytes* per second.  USB HID goes a lot slower, tops out at 8000 bytes per second.  You can arbitrarily make your serial port slower by lowering the baudrate.  Ultimately this is probably a fire-hose problem, you just can't plot the data fast enough.  Nor can the human eye keep up, which is the only thing that really matters.  It is up to you to figure out what you throw away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `SerialPort.ReadBufferSize` is set to 4096 bytes. Slighly more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readbuffersize.aspx). But you can easily change it to accomodate necessary amount of data. Then in `DataReceived` event handler do something like this

```
 static void Serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

       if (Serial.BytesToRead < 24000) return;

               ... //Recieve and process your data here
    }
```

`24000` is given here for example.